# How to change first column background color in Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Hello I have below jsp,

```
<div id="dynamic">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
            id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">First Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Last Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Address 1</th>
                    <th width="10%">Address 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The above code is synced with JQuery Data tables. When I am running it the sorted column is having different color. But I want it to change when I select a row. Could you please help in this?

Comment: Thanks for responses. I tried all the below suggestions but unfortunately non of them are working :( 
**Observation: Only for sorted column, I am not able to change the background-color.**

Answer (score 3):

Good contribution from wi7sonjoseph it was perfect

```
     "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
        $('td', row).eq(2).addClass('warningcolumn');
        $('td', row).eq(3).addClass('warningcolumn');
        $('td', row).eq(15).addClass('warningcolumnok');
        $('td', row).eq(16).addClass('warningcolumnok');
if ( data.OPERATIVIDAD == 1) {
  $('td:eq(6)', row).html('<span class="label label-success">OPERATIVO</span>');
}
else {
  $('td:eq(6)', row).html('<span class="label label-danger">INOPERATIVO</span>');
}}
```

[image]

There is also a good contribution here.
https://jsfiddle.net/jlujan/r041f7mw/

Answer (score 1):

First column with different color is due to the class `display` used by datatable. Remove class `display` from table will do the trick

Refer [Datatable Styling](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/) to know more about its styling

Comment: This is what worked for me. I'm using DataTable 1.10 with Bootstrap 4 but 2.5 years later this is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the first colunm, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example tr").children("td").first().css({"background-color":"#C94BCB"}); // Choose your color!
});
```

About `hover`... It's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use CSS:-**

```
td:first-child {  
  /* your stuff here */
  background-color:#ffffff;    
}
```

If you need for `nth-child` you can specify like this

```
td:nth-child(n) {  
  /* your stuff here */
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Reference Link:- [CSS First-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

Answer (score 0):

Use td and th first-child style

```
th:first-child,td:first-child {  
  background-color:red;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
th:first-child,td:first-child {  
  background-color:red;    
}
</style>
<div id="dynamic">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
            id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">First Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Last Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Address 1</th>
                    <th width="10%">Address 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">First Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Last Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 1</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">First Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Last Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 1</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">First Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Last Name</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 1</td>
                    <td width="10%">Address 2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rowCallBack (Use aData if you want to check some specific field to change color)

```
"rowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            if (aData != null && aData != "") {
                  $('td', nRow).eq(0).css({color: "#f91212"});
            }
          },
```